# Firebase query not returning results everytime it runs

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have implemented a search function in an angular 7 app that uses Firebase. I want the user to provide a from and to values always and a date value optionally. At the moment whenever a user provides all 3 values (from, to & date) the query returns the expected result. But if only from & to values are provided, the query returns expected result sometimes and doesn't at other times. I haven't been able to find a bug in my code so I need you guys to help look at my code to see if I am doing something wrong. Here's my code

schedule.service.ts

```
searchSchedulesList(route: string, date) {
let now = this.formatDate(this.today);

if (date != null) {
  return this.afs
    .collection("schedules", ref =>
      ref
        .where("route", "==", route)
        .where("date", "==", date)
        .where("date", ">=", now)
        .orderBy("date", "asc")
        .orderBy("time", "asc")
    )
    .snapshotChanges();
} else {
  return this.afs
    .collection("schedules", ref => ref.where("route", "==", route))
    .snapshotChanges();
}
}
```

schedule.component.ts

```
search(route: string, date) {
this.scheduleService.searchSchedulesList(route, date).subscribe(data => {
  this.schedules = data.map(e => {
    return {
      id: e.payload.doc.id,
      ...e.payload.doc.data()
    } as Schedule;
  });
});
```

}

This is the search form used to get the values `from` `to` and `date`

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-3">
      <select formControlName="from" id="from" class="form-control">
        <option value="">From</option>
        <option
          *ngFor="let destination of destinations"
          value="{{ destination.abbreviation }}"
          >{{ destination.fullname }}</option
        >
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-3">
      <select formControlName="to" id="to" class="form-control">
        <option value="">To</option>
        <option
          *ngFor="let destination of destinations"
          value="{{ destination.abbreviation }}"
          >{{ destination.fullname }}</option
        >
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-3">
      <input formControlName="date" type="date" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        (click)="
          search(
            searchForm.value.from + searchForm.value.to,
            searchForm.value.date
          )
        "
      >
        Search
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="clear()">
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you query for the `from` and `to`? Through the `route` parameter I guess, but how are these related?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I used a form to get `from` `to` & `date` values. The values for `from` & `to` are then concatenated and used as `route` value. I have added the form code